# how to use subquery with aggregate function in hive

Tags: hiveql

```
SELECT peridle, CPU
FROM (SELECT MAX(peridle) FROM try2);
```

While executing  this query in hive I am getting following error

> Parse Error: line 1:47 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'MAX' '(' in expression specification

Please suggest a solution how to use aggregate functions in hive subquery

Answer (score 1):

At least two things need to be fixed here:

1. You are not returning fields named `peridle` or `CPU` from the sub-query, yet you are trying to select them.
2. Hive requires you to alias all sub-queries, even if you don't reference the alias. You can quickly do this by changing the `);` at the end to `) x;` (or however you want to call it).